# The subscripts in axes lables are not supposed to be smaller in size?

Tags: plotting

When I was to make the axes labels with subscripts, I noticed the subscript is actually of the same size with the standard part, which makes it look very awkward.

`Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {Subscript[a, a], Subscript[N, 1]}]`

With this, the sub `a` and the standard `a` look the same size. Instead, I have to make the sub `a` smaller manually with `Subscript[a, Style[a, 4]]`, where my standard font size is 8. Anyone noticed this before? Are there any better solutions to make the subs smaller automatically?

Comment: I can't really reproduce that behavior. The subscripted expression is in fact smaller, but perhaps at small font sizes the difference is too small to be perceived. At overall larger font sizes the difference is much clearer ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zO8be.png)). The code seems to work as intended, at least on MMA 11 Win7; perhaps this is also OS dependent.

Comment: @MarcoB I am doing it on MMA 11 Win 10. I tried font size 24 and it looks all right. For small font sizes, the subs just look too big. I think the issue just comes up for smaller sized labels.

Comment: I concur with @nanjun (on Mma 10.4).

Comment: You are probably hitting the `ScriptMinSize` limit. You could try something like `Style[Subscript[a, 4], ScriptMinSize->3]`. You could also investigate the `ScriptSizeMultipliers` and `ScriptBaselineShifts` options.

Comment: @Carl Your comment would definitely be a valuable answer, whether or not it directly solves OPs problem. I had no inkling of the existence of `ScriptMinSize` and it would be useful to retain that info in an answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert @Carl Woll's comment to an answer, at small font sizes, superscripts are the same size as the base text by default:

```
Magnify[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^9}, BaseStyle -> {8}, ImageSize -> Small], 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can be remedied with the `ScriptMinSize` style setting, which can be specified in various places, for example in the `BaseStyle` option of plot:

```
Magnify[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^9}, BaseStyle -> {8, ScriptMinSize -> 3}, ImageSize -> Small], 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the excellent answer.